# Cannot cross-reference figure after using \captionof

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions

I'm using `\captionof` instead of `\caption` because I had a problem with the figure environment. Whenever I wrote the code to place two figures and some text between them, the text was placed before the figures, not between them. I read something about this being a problem related to the figure environment and its floating characteristics, so I deleted it and used `\captionof{figure}` instead of `\caption` in order to have a caption.
This seemed a good solution, however, cross-references stopped working. Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
\begin{center}
    \leavevmode
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{AFM1}
    \captionof{figure}{There is a caption here}
    \label{fig:AFM1}
 \end{center}
```

What can I do in order to have cross-references back again and keep the text after the figures while also having captions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as OP recognizes in comments to answer, the problem was due to a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem. Could you be more specific?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Some text before   Fig~\ref{fig:a} and \ref{fig:b}

\begin{center}
    \leavevmode
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{There is a caption here also in Fig \ref{fig:b}}
    \label{fig:a}
\end{center}

Some text between  Fig~\ref{fig:a} and \ref{fig:b}

\begin{center}
    \leavevmode
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{There is a caption here also in Fig \ref{fig:a}}
    \label{fig:b}
 \end{center}

As you can see in Fig~\ref{fig:a} and \ref{fig:b}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm so sorry, my mistake. I was cross-referencing with an unused label name. Thank you!